# How to refresh the id_token of an oauth2client.client?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials object, for which I'd like to refresh the id_token.

This object has a `refresh` method, though this only refreshes the access_token according to the documentation. The refresh method hits the right endpoint (https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token) and receives an HTTP response with a refreshed id_token. But the id_token property for the object itself is not updated.

I'd expect the refresh method to also refresh the id_token. Or least for this object to have *some* method for refreshing the id_token. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly: `But the id_token property for the object itself is not updated.`.  Are you referring to the library not updating its cache or the endpoint is not returning a refreshed ID Token? If you receive an ID Token when refreshing the Access Token, why do you think that it is not updated? Have you verified that the `iat` (Issued at) or the `exp` has not changed?

Comment: Note: `oauth2client` is deprecated. You should switch your code to use `google-auth`. https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html

Comment: The library doesn't update its cache (`iat` and `exp` remain unchanged). The endpoint _does_ return a refreshed id token.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my oauth2client library was out of date, and didn't include this [1](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/pull/337/commits) commit, which refreshes the id_token along with the access_token in OAuth2Credentials.refresh()

Comment: Was the solution to update the library (pip --upgrade) or to apply a patch manually?